# Need help: localized a bug but still can't quash it

Tags: ruby, matrix

The program below is a substantial simplification of one that worked but in spite of hours of effort I can't identify why the following bug occurs:
Everything works as expected except that when the line "if behavior[2,0] > t then goright(brain,stimulus) end" is executed, the line "stimulus.each {|n| stimulus[n,0]=0 }" does NOT reset all of the elements of the stimulus vector to 0 as it does otherwise.  Instead the "1" placed there by the previous trip through the "for c in (0..$Choices)" remains thereby generating double behaviors (both a left and right turn) when only one is expected.  I've commented out everything that I believe is irrelevant yet it still happens.

````
class Matrix
  def []=(i, j, x)
    @rows[i][j] = x
  end
end #code to allow putting individual elements in matrix at i,j
brain=  Matrix[ [90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,90,0,10,10,10,10,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,90,10,10,10,10,0,0,0,0] ]
longmem=Matrix[ [90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,90,0,10,10,10,10,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,90,10,10,10,10,0,0,0,0] ]
stimulus=Matrix.column_vector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
behavior=Matrix.column_vector([0,0,0])
t=89 # t=threshold
# decay_rate=2
$Stimmax=10
$Behavmax=2
$Choices=2
# begin defining behavioral methods
def learn(ix, brain, stimulus)
    psp=20
    for j in (8..$Stimmax)
    if brain[ix,j] > 0 then brain[ix,j]+= 20 end #modified hunting for bug
    end # for j
end # learn
#def positive_fixer(brain,stimulus,longmem,energy)
#   reinf=0.9
#   for i in (0..$Behavmax)
#   for j in (7..$Stimmax)
#      if longmem[i,j]>0 then longmem[i,j]+=(reinf*(brain[i,j]-longmem[i,j])).round end
#    end 
#    end 
#    learn(0, brain, stimulus)
#end #positive fixer comment out in bug hunt
def goleft(brain,stimulus)
    puts "              Left Turn"
    learn(1,brain,stimulus)
end # def left
def goright(brain,stimulus)
    puts "              Right Turn"
    learn(2,brain,stimulus)
end # def right
# end defining behavioral methods

# begin MAIN PROGRAM
for c in (0..$Choices)
stimulus.each {|n| stimulus[n,0]=0 }
# SET ALL STIMS TO O
puts "Should by all 0s"
stimulus.to_a.each {|r| puts r.inspect} # aid in bug hunt

stimulus[rand(1..2),0]= 1
#add print stimulus vector for debugging
puts "Should by just a single 1"
stimulus.to_a.each {|r| puts r.inspect} # aid in bug hunt

# memory decay
#for i in (0..$Behavmax)
#for j in (7..$Stimmax)
#  if brain[i,j]>longmem[i,j] then brain[i,j]+=-(brain[i,j]-longmem[i,j])/decay_rate end
#  if brain[i,j]<longmem[i,j] then brain[i,j]+=-1*((brain[i,j]+longmem[i,j])/decay_rate) end
#end #for j
#end #for i
# memory decay commented out in search for bug

behavior=brain*stimulus
if behavior[0,0] > t then positive_fixer(brain, stimulus, longmem, energy) end
if behavior[1,0] > t then goleft(brain,stimulus) end
if behavior[2,0] > t then goright(brain,stimulus) end
end #for c
puts
brain.to_a.each {|r| puts r.inspect}
# end main program```
````

Comment: "the line "stimulus.each {|n| stimulus[n,0]=0 }" does NOT reset all of the elements of the stimulus vector to 0" When this code runs, what values do you expect `n` to have each time the block is executed? Did you try *checking that*?

Comment: I borrowed that code from another program.  I think n is just an index and it's supposed to look at each element of the vector.  In any case, it does reset all values to O when the program executes "goleft" but does not do so when it executes "goright"

Comment: "and it's supposed to look at each element of the vector." Okay; so if `n` is one of the *elements from* `stimulus`, does it make sense to write `stimulus[n,0]` as a way to find each element of `stimulus`? Also: did you try putting, for example, `ruby clear matrix`, `ruby set each value in matrix`, or anything of that sort into a search engine? What happened when you tried that?

Comment: you may have a point.  checking it out.

Comment: So you were correct.  That code appears not to work, but this did:```for j in (0..$Stimmax)
 if stimulus[j,0] > 0 then stimulus[j,0]=0 end 
 end # for j```  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> the line "stimulus.each {|n| stimulus[n,0]=0 }" does NOT reset all of the elements of the stimulus vector to 0 as it does otherwise

One of the way how to reset vector:

```
require 'matrix'

vector = Matrix.column_vector([1, 2, 3])
# => Matrix[[1], [2], [3]]

vector.each_with_index { |_, i| vector[i, 0] = 0 }
# => Matrix[[0], [0], [0]]
```

So you need to use [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each_with_index) instead of [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each_with_index)